# Missing GLSL functionality

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've moved a Visual Studio project to a different computer and now GLSL won't compile shaders which previously worked fine. It's getting stuck implicitly converting vec4s to vec3s and it tells me the 'dot' function is undefined, for example.

I'm using the GLSDK and the project builds correctly, and glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) tells me 4.40. It's obviously something I don't have installed but used to, but I've searched around and cannot work out what.

Comment: Admittedly I normally deal with GLSL ES, which is why I'm not keen to try this immediately as an answer, but I don't think that implicit conversions between different sizes of vector are part of the spec — types can convert implicitly, sizes can't.

Comment: I've just picked up a project that was working on another computer and dumped it onto this one, so I can confirm that the shader does normally run fine. Aside from conversion it won't recognise the dot(vec3, vec3) function as existing, there would probably be more if I went through and remedied each error.

Comment: Is it possible that it's actually complaining about a missing `dot(vec3, vec4)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, it sounds like your old drivers were being a bit too permissive.  Your new drivers are correct in rejecting the shaders.

```
vec4 a = vec4(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
vec3 x = vec3(a); // Ok
// vec3 y = a;    error
```

Indeed, if I run the implicit conversion through the [reference compiler](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/Reference-Compiler/), I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: 0:4: '=' :  cannot convert from '4-component vector of float' to '3-component vector of float'
ERROR: 1 compilation errors.  No code generated.
```

Try validating your scripts with the [reference compiler](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/Reference-Compiler/), it may catch some portability issues like these.  Your only real option here is to fix the broken shaders.

### What about `dot()`?

Try this:

```
#version 330
void main() {
    vec4 x = vec4(1.0);
    vec3 y = vec3(2.0);
    float z = dot(x, y);
}
```

When I run the validator, I get:

```
ERROR: 0:5: 'dot' : no matching overloaded function found 
ERROR: 1 compilation errors.  No code generated.
```

The error here is that my arguments to `dot()` are the wrong type.  Again, the problem is in my shader.

Comment: Yeah, that's all it was. I was confused because when I changed them to vec4s it made the dot() break further down, leading me to believe I'd not got some GLSL command library or something.